# Converting date/time to a different timeZone using MST7 or AST4 formats

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs, moment-timezone

I will get timeZone from the backend in the form of MST7 or AST4
I have to convert current user time to this timeZone
I am trying to do something like this

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone';
.....
const convertedTime = moment.tz(new Date(), 'AST4').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
```

But I see that moment is not accepting formats MST7 or AST4 and similar other US timeZone in ths format.

Please let me know how I can convert to different USA timesZones by using these formats like MST7 or AST4 etc

Answer (score 1):

The timezones you're supplied with are valid IANA generic timezones (see [`TZ List`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)).

You can use the [`moment.tz`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) constructor to create these as with other IANA zones:

```js
const timeZones = ['EST5EDT', 'CST6CDT', 'MST7MDT', 'PST8PDT'];

console.log('Timezone'.padEnd(20), 'Current Time');
for(let timeZone of timeZones) {
    const convertedTime = moment.tz(timeZone).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
    console.log(timeZone.padEnd(20), convertedTime)
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @terry for the answer. I corrected my question , my question was more on to  'How to covert time to diff timeZone' where some of the USA timeZone formats are not supported. like MST7 or AST4

Comment: FYI - Only a small handful of POSIX time zones are valid IANA time zones, and those are mostly for backwards compatibility purposes.  Their usage is generally discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about your back-end, so I can only speculate, but I believe `"MST7"` and `"AST4"` are *probably* POSIX time zones strings.  You can read more about them in [the `timezone` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), in the section "POSIX style time zones" towards the bottom.

POSIX time zone do not uniquely identify a time zone.  They aren't identifiers.  They only describe some portion of a time zone's behavior.

`"MST7"` means only two things:

- This time zone is labeled "MST"
- This time zone is 7 hours *west* of GMT

Note that the offsets of POSIX time zones are inverted from the typical ISO 8601 standard.  "MST7" has an offset of UTC-7.

Also, because it doesn't give another abbreviation, it implies that daylight saving time is not applicable.  Thus it would be UTC-7 year-round.  However, there's no way of knowing if that is the rule that has *always* applied, or just the one that applies presently.  That is the main problem with them - they're only a snapshot of the time zone at some undefined point in time.

Moment-Timezone (and most other modern libraries and platforms) don't use POSIX time zones.  They use [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) [TZ Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) [identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).  I highly suggest you update the back end of your app to use them as well.

If you *really* must use these POSIX time zone strings, you can refer to [a post I made many years ago](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/314#issuecomment-198226333).  (However, that is about how to generate them, not how to parse them.)

And lastly, keep in mind that Moment.js is considered to have reached end-of-life.  If you are starting a new project, you should choose something else.  See the [Moment Project Status](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) page.  Thanks.